# Why Html.ActionLink isn't working in Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a work around but for my own understanding I'm trying to figure out why an @Html.ActionLink wouldn't work in a Bootstrap Modal?

I created a LogOut controller that does some logging and cleans up some session variables before redirecting. I was able to create a log out link on my Layout page using an @Html.ActionLink without issue. However, I also have a View that uses a Bootstrap Modal on it. When I use the same @Html.ActionLink it doesn't work.

```
@Html.ActionLink("OK", "Index", "LogOut", new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-lg" })
```

When I look at the F12 tools I can see the link is not correct. This is what it created.

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="/?Length=6">OK</a>
```

However, if I use a @Url.Action in an anchor tag instead it works fine. This is what works.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index","LogOut")' class="btn btn-success btn-lg">OK</a>
```

I'm okay with using the @Url.Action but I'm just trying to learn why the @Html.ActionLink wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `ActionLink` overload wrong!

Try this overload.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

The 4th parameter is for passing route values(querystring values) and 5th is for html attributes of the link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("OK", "Index", "LogOut", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-lg" })
```

Comment: That was it. I'm assuming here is no difference in using either the @Html.Actionlink or the @Url.Action?

Comment: `Url.Action` produces the relative path to that specific action method. `Html.ActionLink` produces the markup for an `a` tag with the proper `href` attribute value.